# Batch file with non-ASCII characters

Tags: batch-file

I need to link to a folder that contains the character "æ" in a batch script.

I run into trouble when I run the script though. The command prompt misreads the non-ASCII characters. I've tried saving the file as both ANSI and Unicode. I'm running Windows 7.

Here's a minimal example:

```
echo øl
```

Comment: Ugh, I know how to fix this, but I don't know enough of the mechanics behind it for a proper answer. Basically, replace `æ` with `‘` (that's ALT+0145).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is used neither **ANSI** nor **Unicode** by default in console windows. Windows uses by default for console an **OEM** code page.

Which **OEM** code page is used depends on Windows country/region and language settings. The default OEM code page is [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) for USA and Canada and [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) for most Western European countries.

The non-Unicode code page in graphical user interface (GUI) windows is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) for USA, Canada and most Western European countries.

The character [æ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) has the decimal code value **230** (hex. E6) in code page Windows-1252 as well as in the Unicode table. But the decimal code value of this character is **145** (hex. 91) in OEM code pages 437 and 850.

So, this character must be inserted into the batch file either with inserting the Windows-1252 encoded character `‘` or there is edited the batch file in text editor directly using the appropriate OEM code page.

I'm using UltraEdit for editing text files. I have configured UltraEdit using automatically the OEM code page as defined by the system (code page 850 in my case) for files with extension BAT and CMD and use for all other non-Unicode text files the system code page for GUI windows (code page 1252 in my case). UltraEdit makes also the necessary conversion from Unicode or Windows-1252 to OEM code page 850 on pasting a text copied for example in web browser into the batch file. And UltraEdit converts the OEM encoded characters also from 850 to 1252 and Unicode on copying a selected text in batch file to clipboard.

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window and run either command `chcp` or `mode con` for finding out which OEM code page is used on a Windows computer in console windows for the current user account.

Answer (score 2):

I use Notepad++. Choose first encoding (OEM 850 for exemple) and type normally.